# Installing Grunt, osx, nvm, zsh

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, ghost-blog

Installing Grunt

I have osx yosemite, zsh, nvm. The version of node I am using is v0.10.33.

I installed node in a way I do not need to use sudo (node and npm reside in my home folder)

here where I export the global dependencies in my zshrc

```
export NODE_PATH=/Users/nickname/.node/lib/node_modules/:/Users/nickname/.node/lib/node_modules
```

Just for information, I am trying to install Ghost (the blogging plataform).

I cloned like this to get the stable version

`git clone -b stable https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost.git ghost`

and then

```
cd ghost/
git submodule update --init
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
grunt init
```

The error I am getting is that is not able to find grunt

`Ghost git:(stable) grunt init
zsh: command not found: grunt`

Comment: Can you tell us what errors you are receiving?

Comment: @jakerella sorry, my bad, I edited the question. I install  the grunt-cli globally, but I am getting the same, maybe I should modify the zshrc file. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to install `grunt` globally, only [`grunt-cli`](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli). The `grunt` package should be [installed in your project directory](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#working-with-an-existing-grunt-project) using something like:

```
~$ npm install grunt --save-dev
```

That will add a line to your project's `package.json` file, then you [configure a "Gruntfile.js"](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#the-gruntfile) for your project with tasks that are run from the command line with:

```
~$ grunt taskname
```

Comment: Thank you @jakerella for the answer. Is not working, just for information, I am cloning ghost (the blog plataform) and trying to install it, so grunt is in the package json.

Comment: So how did you install Ghost? Did you do a `git clone` or `npm install ghost`? In any case, you still **should not be installing grunt globally**. You can install all dependencies using `npm install` (but you have to run that from he project root directory).

Comment: I still didn't get ghost to run. I tried with git clone. Maybe the problem that I am facing is related with grunt and nvm. I will try to find the solution, thanks

Comment: Finally I remove node and nvm from my system (all folders). I reinstalled nvm. Organized my zshrc file. and worked. I will mark your answer as the correct because told me important information to solve the problem. thank you @jakerella